# Nginx URL with UTF-8

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I just installed a fresh server with Nginx, to run my client wordpress blog. The blog was migrated from an old server with Apache.

It's almost everything OK, but I'm getting 404 errors with image names that contain special characters.

For example, the link **/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Workshop-de-Tricô-e-Crochê-Círculo.png** results in a 404 error.

Checking the server inputs, this URL becomes **/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Workshop-de-Tric%C3%B4-e-Croch%C3%AA-C%C3%ADrculo.png**, and because of that results in a 404 error.

My server configuration is this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.mysite.com;
    root /home/forge/blog.mysite.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    access_log off;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: If you do an `ls` on the server are the filenames showing up correctly?

Comment: Yes, with and `ls` the files are correct.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with nginx so this might be a dumb idea. It looks like you've got nginx configured to pass 404's over to WordPress to handle, right? Can you tell if nginx is 404'ing or if it is successfully handing the query, passing it to WordPress and WordPress can't find it causing the 404? The former case would then an nginx configuration problem but the latter case might be debuggable/solvable at the wp_query level.

Comment: Actually nginx pass to wordpress, and wordpress cause the 404 error. But in this case I'm trying to access a file that technically doesn't exists, so, the 404 error is OK.

Comment: WordPress generally doesn't kick in for things in `uploads`, that's what I'm trying to figure out. The normal apache .htaccess directive is "if there isn't a FILE or a DIRECTORY at this url then pass it to index.php, thus invoking WordPress, otherwise bypass WordPress and send the file directly". You've got that covered with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`. However, the fact that the query is making it to WordPress in the first place tells me that nginx can't locate the file on disk so I think you've got a configuration problem there.

Comment: Are your static files stored inside your document root? Seems like nginx cant find the file and passes the request to php (wordpress)

Comment: Yes, the file is there with the name `Workshop-de-Tricô-e-Crochê-Círculo.png`. Seems to me that nginx is trying to find the file `Workshop-de-Tric%C3%B4-e-Croch%C3%AA-C%C3%ADrculo.png`, replacing the accents. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was:

My Mac (I don't know how), changed the files charset when I copy the files to the new server.
When I made the same process in a Ubuntu machine, worked very well. Thank's for the answers.

Comment: See also [“Rsync with special character files not working between Mac and Linux”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533690/rsync-with-special-character-files-not-working-between-mac-and-linux/540960#540960) on Ask Ubuntu. I encountered this problem when using the outdated builtin version 2.6 of `rsync` from a Mac to an Ubuntu server without `--iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8`. Before installing version 3.1 with Homebrew and adding `iconv`, filenames were decomposed into NFD in Ubuntu. Also see [“Filenames with accents”](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201106/filenames_with_accents.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i tested your nginx scenario without wordpress using my local installation and i dont have any issues with the file name. Could you double check the file location? You could try to create a simple setup without wordpress to debug your situation, and did you look at your access.log file?

Enclosed is my testsetup.

The file Workshop-de-Tricô-e-Crochê-Círculo.png is stored directly in the path /data/nginx-test

```
1,4M 18 Jul 22:33 Workshop-de-Tricô-e-Crochê-Círculo.png
```

nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name test.*;

        root /data/nginx-test;
        index index.php;

    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
        }
}
```

request/response headers:

```
Remote Address:192.168.33.10:80
Request URL:http://test.vg/Workshop-de-Tric%C3%B4-e-Croch%C3%AA-C%C3%ADrculo.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:test.vg
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1486529
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Fri, 18 Jul 2014 20:36:54 GMT
ETag:"53c98490-16aec1"
Last-Modified:Fri, 18 Jul 2014 20:33:20 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.0
```